# How create custom field admin grid?

Tags: magento2

Good evening. I just recently started learning magento 2 and faced the following problem. I have an XML form that contains information, such as "Name, address, telephone"
I need to create a block that will return which fields will be in the fieldset, but I dont know how
I think that I'm calling the wrong class, I ask for help.
Ty
my code:

form.xml

```
<fieldset class="[Vendor]\[Module]\Block\Adminhtml\[Module]\Edit\Tab\Checkbox" />
```

di.xml

```
<preference for="Magento\Tax\Block\Adminhtml\Rate\Form" type="[Vendor]\[Module]\Block\Adminhtml\[Module]\Edit\Tab\Checkbox" />
```

[Vendor][Module]\Block\Adminhtml[Module]\Edit\Tab\Checkbox.php

```
class Checkbox extends \Magento\Tax\Block\Adminhtml\Rate\Form
{

    protected $_taxData = null;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Tax\Block\Adminhtml\Rate\Title\FieldsetFactory
     */
    protected $_fieldsetFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Directory\Model\Config\Source\Country
     */
    protected $_country;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Directory\Model\RegionFactory
     */
    protected $_regionFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Tax\Api\TaxRateRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $_taxRateRepository;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Tax\Model\TaxRateCollection
     */
    protected $_taxRateCollection;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Tax\Model\Calculation\Rate\Converter
     */
    protected $_taxRateConverter;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory
     * @param \Magento\Directory\Model\RegionFactory $regionFactory
     * @param \Magento\Directory\Model\Config\Source\Country $country
     * @param \Magento\Tax\Block\Adminhtml\Rate\Title\FieldsetFactory $fieldsetFactory
     * @param \Magento\Tax\Helper\Data $taxData
     * @param \Magento\Tax\Api\TaxRateRepositoryInterface $taxRateRepository
     * @param \Magento\Tax\Model\TaxRateCollection $taxRateCollection
     * @param \Magento\Tax\Model\Calculation\Rate\Converter $taxRateConverter
     * @param array $data
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
        \Magento\Directory\Model\RegionFactory $regionFactory,
        \Magento\Directory\Model\Config\Source\Country $country,
        \Magento\Tax\Block\Adminhtml\Rate\Title\FieldsetFactory $fieldsetFactory,
        \Magento\Tax\Helper\Data $taxData,
        \Magento\Tax\Api\TaxRateRepositoryInterface $taxRateRepository,
        \Magento\Tax\Model\TaxRateCollection $taxRateCollection,
        \Magento\Tax\Model\Calculation\Rate\Converter $taxRateConverter,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $regionFactory, $country, $fieldsetFactory, $taxData, $taxRateRepository, $taxRateCollection, $taxRateConverter, $data);

    }


    /**
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
    }


    public function _prepareForm()
    {
        parent::_prepareForm();

            $form = $this->getForm();
            $fieldset = $form->п('new_fieldset',
                array('legend'=>'GST Tax Rate Information')
            );
            $fieldset->addField('hsn_title', 'text',
                array(
                    'label' => 'HSN Code',
                    'class' => 'input-text',
                    'name'  => 'hsn_title',
                    'required' => false
                )
            );

            $this->setForm($form);
            return $this;
    }
```

Comment: add xml form...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

custom filed in admin grid can be added in XML file.  This XML file is created under view/adminhtml/layout and also view/adminhtml/layout/ui_component folders.

In view/adminhtml/layout create layout file which should be something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="styles"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="frontname_controlername_listing"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

In view/adminhtml/layout/ui_component folder

create a file which should be mentioned in above layout file in this example it is **frontname_controlername_listing**

this XML file includes many things and you just wanted custom field to add so adding code specific to that.

```
<column name="name of filed">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Name of filed </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
```